# After a fixed date change the code

Tags: java

If I have a .jar file with all the .class files, and I want that after the 15th of December the program must not start.

So, if I open that .jar on the 16th of December the program will changes a part of the code o destroys a .class file.

For example:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();  
Calendar expires = Calendar.getInstance();  
expires.set(2013,11,15,0,0);
if(today.after(expires)) {  
    *** code that changes a part of the code or destroys a .class file ***
}
```

Is it possible?

edit:
The System.exit(1) is not an option.

edit2:
If I have a .jar file with all the .class files, and I want that after the 15th of December the program must not start - **anymore** -.

Comment: Is this about implementing some kind of license management?

Comment: Yes, because I use my software in a lot of pc, and I do not want my program being "stolen" by strangers without asking permission to me.

Answer (score 3):

> I want that after the 15th of december the program must not start.

Use `System.exit(0)`,

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();  
Calendar expires = Calendar.getInstance();  
expires.set(2013,11,15,0,0);
if(today.after(expires)) {  
   System.exit(0);
}
```

**Note that,** this way program will get the System time. If user changes PC time than he/she will able to run the Program.

Comment: Now I'm using that code, but if I set the calendar to 14th of december, and I'm on the 16th of december the program will works. So here I need to change a part of the code in such a way the program will not start anymore.

Comment: @delvedor, Try to change PC time to 20th December than it will not run.

Comment: Obviously. But in this way if a person know it, my trick is unuseful.

Comment: I answered your comment with edit2, sorry for the imprecision.